# ssh check validity of known_hosts fingerprint

Tags: ssh

One of my Debian machines (all using some more-or-less recent version of OpenSSH) has got some fingerprints of remote machines in the known_hosts file. From time to time this remote machines get reinstalled and so they get a new fingerprint. When I now try to connect, I get the famous 'remote host identification has changed' error message instead of a working connection.

I already have a small script which can repair this situation. But my problem is to detect it automatically in a scripted way.

What I want to implement now is some other script, running in background at some time, which detects if a 'remote host identification has changed' situation occurred. If so, it should start my repair-script.

I already have some ideas for dirty hacks. Maybe I can parse the output for the error message. Or maybe I can try with and without host verification and trigger the event if only the latter one succeeds. But I wonder if there is a more clean way to detect that in an automated way.

Does anybody have an idea for that? Entirely turning off the host verification is not a working alternative of course. It might be that I don't see the wood for the trees currently...

Comment: ... it can also happen that the remote machines are turned off. I have to distingush between a changed fingerprint and other errors. It is not enough to just detect the impossibility to establish a connection.

Comment: known_hosts does not contain fingerprints; it contains _public key_ values (in base64, plus a type label). `ssh` compares the public key received to the public key in known_hosts, and if they differ (or the host isn't in known_hosts and you don't use option to accept that) it _displays_ the fingerprint as a value for you to check (though almost no one does). Note however if you automatically accept any key change you receive e.g. with ssh-keyscan, without confirming offline or out-of-band, that's equivalent to turning off verification entirely; you are equally vulnerable (or not) to MitM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple script. When run, if the ssh key change, it print the name server. The file servers have the ip or names.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rm new
while read server
do
        ssh-keyscan $server >> new  2> /dev/null
        diff new org 2> /dev/null | grep ">" | cut -d" " -f 2
        cp new org
done < servers
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't tested the complete script at once, but just the ssh-keyscan path. But I see that it returns the actual remote fingerprint and I can imagine how to proceed from here.